# SQL Server Agent job completes but VBScript doesn't run

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, sql-server-agent

I have the follow script

```
file = "C:\Ristken Data Load\Wade SPIFF log file"
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(file)
oBook.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

oBook.Worksheets(2).Activate
oBook.Worksheets(2).Rows("1:4").Delete

oBook.SaveAs file, -4158
oBook.Close True
oExcel.Quit
```

I can run the script in Visual Studios just fine and it creates the needed file. It is the first step of an SSIS package that is scheduled through SQL Server Agent. When SQL Server Agent kicks off the script it finishes with a "success" result but the VBScript didn't actually create the file.

I've spent hours researching this and I've read multiple posts on stackoverflow with similar issues but no success.

This post seemed to have the most related issue.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d4eb7a73-0549-413f-811e-0105f9861cea/vbscript-runs-correctly-from-command-prompt-but-not-from-sql-server-agent-job?forum=sqlgetstarted

As a result I made a .bat file to call the VBScript. Same results. It completes but the script never runs. I tried a .cmd file and I get the same result.

I'd like to try and avoid converting the script to .NET because I have no experience with .NET.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Instead of writing an excel file, try just writing a text file. Also put some Echo lines in there in a few spots so you can get an idea of where it dies - or whether it even starts (wscript.echo "whatever"), and in your call to the .bat output to a text file  (richardsbatfile.bat > outputfile.txt)   ... and Echos should land in the outputfile.txt ... that should give you more info to go on.

Comment: I'll have to look into adding some echo lines. That might help to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jen R.  Try writing out to TXT or even CSV and see if it even gets that far first.